# JavaScript - SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number Error

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I am having issues with my page loading on Microsoft Edge. I'm getting an `SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number`. I've gone through the different replies on other posts most of them seem to point at misplaced commas in objects or adding quotations around the objects name, i've gone through my code and I am unable to get rid of the error that displays for edge only. My page is working fine on Firefox and chrome.

With this section I have three 2D arrays that I loop through to create 3 separate array of objects. such as :

```
for (let i = 0; i < revenueData[0].length; i++) {
    revenueArr.push({ 'title': revenueData[0][i][4].split(" ").slice(0, -3).join(" "), 'revenueGrowth': revenueData[0][i][5] })
}

for (let i = 0; i < employData[0].length; i++) {
    employArr.push({ 'employGrowth': employData[0][i][6] })
}

for (let i = 0; i < businessData[0].length; i++) {
    businessArr .push({ 'businessGrowth': businessData[0][i][6] })
}
```

Which in return I am combining all 3 separate arrays into one using the spread operator and map.

```js
const revenueArr = [{title: 'online', revenue: 34321, revenueGrowth: 3.2},{title: 'retail', revenue: 321, revenueGrowth: 1.2} ] 

const employArr = [ { employGrowth: 0.2 }, {employGrowth: -1.2} ]


const businessArr = [ {businessGrowth: 2.8}, {businessGrowth: 1.6} ] 


const allData = revenueArr.map((it, index) => {
    return { ...it, ...employArr[index], ...businessArr[index]}
}) 

console.log(allData)
```

---

My error specially is coming from the spread operator and map piece :

```
const allData = revenueArr.map((it, index) => {
    return { ...it, ...employArr[index], ...businessArr[index]}
})
```

Comment: To be clear, this is non-Chromium Edge, right? Because I don't see any errors in Edge Version 85.0.564.17 (Official build) dev (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes this is a non-Chromium Edge version, in this case would the issue be more specific to browser compatibility rather then the error itself?

Comment: See the [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Browser_compatibility) table for spread syntax. This requires Edge version 79.

Comment: I have try to make several tests to make the code work for the Edge browser but it looks like it is not possible to make your code work for the Edge legacy browser. I suggest try to use different logic to merge the arrays.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT do you have any recommendations on what to look into to merge the arrays? All the possible solutions i've come across uses the spread operator

Comment: Please refer to the answer in this thread that may give you the hints. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163253/javascript-object-array-mapping-and-matching-with-ie11/63168063#63168063