# Javascript: object array mapping and matching with IE11

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, internet-explorer-11

I'm looking for a javascript implementation (for IE11) for this problem; my inputs are two arrays like these:

```
var array1 = [{id: 1, param:"bon jour"}, {id: 2, param:"Hi"}, {id: 3, param:"Hello"}];

var array2 = [{item: "Peter", values:"1,2", singlevalue:"2"}, 
              {item: "Mark", values:"1,2,3", singlevalue:"3"}, 
              {item: "Lou", values:"2", singlevalue:"2"}];
```

and I should create a new array (array3) with array2 data plus 2 new fields ("params" and "singleparam"), using matching between array1[i].id and array2[x].values to evaluate "params" and between array1[i].id and array2[x].singlevalue to evaluate "singleparam", with this kind of result:

```
array3 = [{item: "Peter", values:"1,2", singlevalue:"2", params:"bon jour,Hi", singleparam:"Hi"}, 
       {item: "Mark", values:"1,2,3", singlevalue:"3", params:"bon jour,Hi,Hello", singleparam:"Hello"}, 
      {item: "Lou", values:"2", singlevalue:"2", params:"Hi", singleparam:"Hi"}];
```

I'm a javascript newbie and I've tried this kind of solution:

```
var array3 = array2.map(function(x, array1)
{
  const newOb = {};
  newOb.item = x.item;
  newOb.values = x.values;
  newOb.singlevalue = x.singlevalue;
  newOb.params = function(x.values, array1)
  {
    var str = "";
    var idArray = x.values.split(",");
    for(i = 0; i < idArray.lenght; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; i < array1.lenght; j++)
        {
          if(idArray[i] == array1[j].id)
          {
            str += array1[j].param + ",";
            break;
          }
        }
    }
    return str;
  };
  
  newOb.singleparam = function(x.singlevalue, array1)
  {
    var val;
    for(j = 0; i < array1.lenght; j++)
    {
      if(array1[j].id == x.singlevalue)
        val = array1[j].param;
    }
    return val;
  }
  
  return newOb;

});

console.log(array3);
```

with this error: *Error: Unexpected token '.'*

I'd like to find an efficient solution considering that array1 has less than 10 elements, but array2 could contains more than 1000 objects.

Thanks in advance for your support

Comment: You should add the line of the error, so it's more simple to see what the compiler doesn't like.

Comment: `function(x.singlevalue array1)` is a syntax error anywhere, not just IE11

Comment: I'm really sorry, I've lost comma pasting the function : function(x.singlevalue, array1)

Answer (score 1):

I will skip the functions stop and singlevalues and there were also some syntax errors,
for example the correct one is **length** and not leng**ht**

```js
var array1 = [{id: 1, param:"bon jour"}, {id: 2, param:"Hi"}, {id: 3, param:"Hello"}];

var array2 = [{item: "Peter", values:"1,2", singlevalue:"2"}, 
              {item: "Mark", values:"1,2,3", singlevalue:"3"}, 
              {item: "Lou", values:"2", singlevalue:"2"}];

function newArray3() {
    return array2.map(x =>    {
        const newOb = {};
        newOb.item = x.item;
        newOb.values = x.values;
        newOb.singlevalue = x.singlevalue;
        newOb.params = paramsFunction(x.values, array1);
        newOb.singleparam = singleParamFunction(x.singlevalue, array1);
        return newOb;
    })
}

function singleParamFunction(x, array1) {
    var val;
    for(i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
      if(array1[i].id.toString() == x) {
             val = array1[i].param;
       }
    }
    return val;
}

function paramsFunction(x, array1) {
    var str = "";
    var idArray = x.split(",");
    
    for(i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < array1.length; j++)
        {
          if(idArray[i] == array1[j].id.toString())
          {
            str += array1[j].param + ",";
            break;
          }
        }
    }
    return str;
}

array3 = newArray3();

console.log(array3)
```

Comment: Good hints. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by the @Walteann Costa can show the desired results in other browsers but it will not work for the IE browser as his code sample uses the => Arrow functions that is not supported in the IE browser.

As your question asks the solution for the IE browser, I tried to modify the code sample provided by the @Walteann Costa. Below modified code can work with the IE 11 browser.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";

var array1 = [{
  id: 1,
  param: "bon jour"
}, {
  id: 2,
  param: "Hi"
}, {
  id: 3,
  param: "Hello"
}];
var array2 = [{
  item: "Peter",
  values: "1,2",
  singlevalue: "2"
}, {
  item: "Mark",
  values: "1,2,3",
  singlevalue: "3"
}, {
  item: "Lou",
  values: "2",
  singlevalue: "2"
}];

function newArray3() {
  return array2.map(function (x) {
    var newOb = {};
    newOb.item = x.item;
    newOb.values = x.values;
    newOb.singlevalue = x.singlevalue;
    newOb.params = paramsFunction(x.values, array1);
    newOb.singleparam = singleParamFunction(x.singlevalue, array1);
    return newOb;
  });
}

function singleParamFunction(x, array1) {
  var val,i,j;

  for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (array1[i].id.toString() == x) {
      val = array1[i].param;
    }
  }

  return val;
}

function paramsFunction(x, array1) {
  var str = "";
  var idArray = x.split(",");
  var i,j;
  for (i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
      if (idArray[i] == array1[j].id.toString()) {
        str += array1[j].param + ",";
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return str;
}

var array3 = newArray3();
console.log(array3[0]);
console.log(array3[1]);
console.log(array3[2]);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Output in the IE 11:

[image]

Comment: Good! I've modified paramsFunction to return "str.slice(0, -1);" instead of "str". Thank you!

Comment: If your issue is solved by the suggestions provided on this thread then I suggest you please try to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.